# WooCommerce plugin won't let me access settings

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors, user-access

I downloaded WooCommerce and activated it normally. But it doesn't show up in my Wordpress sidebar to access the settings. When I do it from the plugins page it directs to a page that tells me that I do not have access to this page.[image: sorry-redirect]

Comment: Your user role doesn't seem to have the required [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Comment: I'm the only user on the page set at Administrator? What else do I need to change?

Comment: You'll need to ask the plugin developers.